# Waveform Audio via Callback, no data received

Tags: c#, windows, winmm

I am trying to use the WaveForm Audio functions in C# to read from a microphone. Now I have no past experience with this library so it may just be that I am missing something obvious.

I am able to successfully (no errors returned at least) open a device, add a buffer, and start that device. As follows:

```
short nChannels = 2;
uint nSamplesPerSec = 44100;
short nBitsPerSample = 16;
uint DeviceID = 0;

WAVEFORMATEX Format = new WAVEFORMATEX();
Format.wFormatTag = 0x0001;
Format.nChannels = nChannels;
Format.nSamplesPerSec = nSamplesPerSec;
Format.wBitsPerSample = nBitsPerSample;
Format.nAvgBytesPerSec = ((uint)nBitsPerSample / 8) * nSamplesPerSec;
Format.nBlockAlign = (short)((nChannels * nBitsPerSample) / 8);
Format.cbSize = 0;

WAVEHDR BufHeader = new WAVEHDR();
BufHeader.lpData = Marshal.AllocHGlobal((int)Format.nAvgBytesPerSec);
BufHeader.dwBufferLength = Format.nAvgBytesPerSec;
BufHeader.dwUser = 0;
BufHeader.dwFlags = 0;

uint err;
err = waveInOpen(ref HWI, DeviceID, ref Format, new waveInProc(waveInCbk), 0, 0x00030000);
err = waveInPrepareHeader(HWI, ref BufHeader, (uint)Marshal.SizeOf(typeof(WAVEHDR)));
err = waveInAddBuffer(HWI, ref BufHeader, (uint)Marshal.SizeOf(typeof(WAVEHDR)));
err = waveInStart(HWI);
```

Note that I have checked the value of err, via the debugger, and it is always 0. Additionally, i have looked into the properties of Device 0. Its default audio format when being shared is 44.1 kHz, 2 channel, 16 bps (as I am using). The callback function used is:

```
private void waveInCbk(IntPtr hwi, WAVEINCBKMSG uMsg, IntPtr dwInstance, IntPtr dwParam1, IntPtr dwParam2)
{
    switch(uMsg)
    {
        case WAVEINCBKMSG.WIM_CLOSE:
            break;
        case WAVEINCBKMSG.WIM_OPEN:
            break;
        case WAVEINCBKMSG.WIM_DATA:
            System.Console.WriteLine("Received data!"); // Never Reached!
            break;
    }            
}
```

Also of note, the callback is succesfully called once with WIM_OPEN, after my call to waveinOpen. If necessary I can post up my pinvoke's for the wave functions, but for the most part they are from pinvoke.net.

Can anyone spot anything wrong with the above code that would explain why I am not getting any data? Any input is much appreciated. Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well I seem to have solved the issue. I'll post the reason here for others who encounter the same problem.

I have simply added more than 1 buffer. In doing this I now receive data through the callback!

Comment: How do you stop it? waveInReset? Does it come to WIM_CLOSE?